# Virtual sound card driver for Windows

Tags: windows, drivers, audio, sound-card

I have no sound card on my machine, but I want to (automatically) record screen with audio on it. So I thing it's some kind of virtual sound card driver needed to loop back sound send to play to microphone. Is there such solution for Windows OS?

Comment: +1 This is one weird question. **Nice**, but weird.

Comment: Virtual Audio card (Lakeofsoft) unfortunately does not seem to work on Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure I 100% understand your question, but you might want to check out:

http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html

sounds like this might fit your requirements.

Comment: "Virtual Audio Cable" costs $30. I guess you can buy a cheap audio card for that price.

Comment: There is a free trial version limited to 3 virtual cables. This may be enough for artem.tikhomirov

Comment: @user, the trial version has a voice saying “trial” every fer seconds, so it's not actually very useful

Comment: There are also other similar drivers, like [VSC](http://www.e2esoft.cn/vsc/vscsdk.asp) (which seemed to have better pricing for our purposes).

Answer (score 1):

A cheaper virtual sound card with the same function. http://www.shiningmorning.com/VirtualAudioStreaming/index.html

Also includes a virtual webcam to broadcast/record screen/file. May consider the virtual audio+webcam package.

Comment: Actually, it's currently only 5 cents cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

possibly of interest:

https://serverfault.com/questions/19601/virtual-sound-card-for-windows-server

or

> http://www.datanab.com/audio/VAcard.htm
>
> Virtual Audio Card
>
> It's free and it works on Windows XP
> and it creates 3 Virtual Audio Cables
> as Windows Sound drivers.
>
> It comes from a software kit for a
> commercial TCP/IP mp3 streaming
> device. Go figure. Works for me in
> place of VAC (Virtual Audio Cable) but
> the latency on my machine is pretty
> awful. YMMV
>
> (from: http://club.myce.com/f57/creating-virtual-sound-card-win2k3-enterprise-server-170878/#post2530866)